# How to use `getBounds' with STArray?

Tags: arrays, haskell, random, shuffle

I'm trying to write a Fisher-Yates shuffle algorithm using STArray. Unlike all the other examples I've found on the net, I am trying to avoid using native lists. I just want to shuffle an array, in-place.

This is what I have:

```
randShuffleST arr gen = runST $ do
    _ <- getBounds arr
    return (arr, gen)
```

`arr` is the STArray and `gen` will be a generator state of type (RandomGen g).

I was hoping I could rely on the `(MArray (STArray s) e (ST s))` [instance declaration](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/0.4.0.1/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html) defined in MArray for being able to use MArray's `getBounds` but GHCi cannot infer the type of `randShuffleST`. It fails with:

```
Could not deduce (MArray a e (ST s))
  arising from a use of `getBounds'
from the context (Ix i)
  bound by the inferred type of
           randShuffleST :: Ix i => a i e -> t -> (a i e, t)
  at CGS/Random.hs:(64,1)-(66,25)
Possible fix:
  add (MArray a e (ST s)) to the context of
    a type expected by the context: ST s (a i e, t)
    or the inferred type of
       randShuffleST :: Ix i => a i e -> t -> (a i e, t)
  or add an instance declaration for (MArray a e (ST s))
In a stmt of a 'do' block: _ <- getBounds arr
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `do { _ <- getBounds arr;
        return (arr, gen) }'
In the expression:
  runST
  $ do { _ <- getBounds arr;
         return (arr, gen) }
```

Interestingly, if I remove the call to `runST' like so:

```
randShuffleST arr gen = do
    _ <- getBounds arr
    return (arr, gen)
```

it compiles fine, with the type signature

```
randShuffleST :: (Ix i, MArray a e m) => a i e -> t -> m (a i e, t)
```

. I'm using GHC 7.4.2 on Arch Linux.

Please give explicit type signatures in your responses to help me understand your code, thank you.

EDIT: I really like Antal S-Z's answer, but I cannot select it because frankly I do not fully understand it. Maybe once I understand my own problem better I'll answer my own question in the future... thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is one way of implementing an in-place Fisher-Yates (I think that is
called a Durstenfeld or Knuth Shuffle). Notice that `runST` is never called, but `runSTArray` instead, and it is only called once.

```
import Data.Array
import Data.Array.ST
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad
import System.Random

fisherYates :: (RandomGen g,Ix ix, Random ix) => g -> Array ix e -> Array ix e
fisherYates gen a' = runSTArray $ do
  a <- thaw a'
  (bot,top) <- getBounds a
  foldM (\g i -> do
    ai <- readArray a i
    let (j,g') = randomR (bot,i) g
    aj <- readArray a j
    writeArray a i aj
    writeArray a j ai
    return g') gen (range (bot,top))    
  return a
```

Note that although the algorithm is performed in-place, the function first copies the array given in the input (a result of using the function `thaw`) before performing the algorithm on the copy. In order to avoid copying the array you have at least two options:

1. Use `unsafeThaw`, which is (as the name suggests) unsafe and can only be used if you
    are sure that the input array will never be used again. This is not trivial to 
    guarantee because of lazy evaluation.
2. Let `fisherYates` have the type `(RandomGen g,Ix ix, Random ix) => g -> STArray s ix e -> ST s (STArray s ix e)` and perform the whole operation that requires an in-place fisher-yates algorithm inside the `ST` monad and only give the final answer with `runST`.

Comment: +1 for a working solution. Even though it's not exactly what I asked for (use of `runST`), I *adore* real, concise, working examples.

Answer (score 8):

You probably shouldn't use `runST` in your function. `runST` should be used once, on the outside of some computation that uses mutation internally but has a pure interface. You probably want your shuffle function, which shuffles the array in-place, to have a type like `STArray s i e -> ST s ()` (or possibly a more general type), and then have a different function that uses `runST` to present a pure interface, if you want that (that function would probably need to copy values, though). In general the goal of `ST` is that `STRef`s and `STArray`s can never escape from one `runST` invocation and be used in another.

The type inferred for your function without `runST` is fine, just more polymorphic (it'll work for IO arrays, ST arrays, STM arrays, unboxed arrays, etc.). You'll have an easier time with inference errors if you specify explicit type signatures, though.

Comment: Well, here is a random shuffle (Fischer-Yates, I think) from the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Random_shuffle) that uses runST internally and has a pure interface (shuffle'). I'm trying to make an array-only version of that function. I don't understand why you think that having a different function that uses runST to call the ST-monadic shuffle function will make any difference, especially considering that the shuffle' function from the wiki itself uses runST and presents a pure interface --- exactly as you suggested.

Comment: You asked for an in-place shuffle, which is very different from the example given on the wiki (or by the other answer). The example copies the input list into an array, shuffles the array in-place, and then copies it back. If you wanted an actual in-place shuffle, it couldn't use `ST` internally while keeping a pure interface. On the other hand, if you had the in-place code, it would be easy to use `runST` with a couple of copies (or `runSTArray`) to give it a pure interface.

Comment: @shachaf, I assume that you were referring to my answer (correct me if I am wrong). Yes it does copy the array first and then does the in-place shuffle, however, fixing this is simply exchanging `thaw` with `unsafethaw`.

Comment: In which case it becomes an unsafe function that mutates an immutable array? That sounds broken to me. If you want a function that shuffles an array in-place, give it a type that reflects that; in this case that type might involve ST.

Comment: @shachaf true, I have changed my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 6):

This occurs because the rank-2 type of `runST` is preventing you from giving a meaningful type to `randShuffleST`.  (There's a second problem with your code as written: mutable ST arrays can't meaningfully exist outside of the `ST` monad, so returning one from inside `runST` is impossible, and constructing one to pass into a pure function is unlikely at best.  This is "uninteresting," but might end up being confusing on its own; see the bottom of this answer for how to address it.)

So, let's see why you can't write down a type signature.  It's worth saying up-front that [I agree with shachaf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12848618/237428) about the best way to write functions like the one you're writing: stay inside `ST`, and use `runST` only once, at the very end.  If you do this, then I've included some sample code at the bottom of the answer which shows how to write your code successfully.  But I think it's interesting to understand why you get the error you do; errors like the one you're getting are some of the reasons that you don't want to write your code this way!

To begin with, let's first look at a simplified version of the function which produces the same error message:

```
bounds arr = runST (getBounds arr)
```

Now, let's try to give a type to `bounds`.  The obvious choice is

```
bounds :: (MArray a e (ST s), Ix i) => a i e -> (i,i)
bounds arr = runST (getBounds arr)
```

We know that `arr` must be an `MArray` and we don't care what elements or index type it has (as long as its indices are in `Ix`), but we know that it must live inside the `ST` monad.  So this should work, right?  Not so fast!

```
ghci> :set -XFlexibleContexts +m
ghci> :module + Control.Monad.ST Data.Array.ST
ghci> let bounds :: (MArray a e (ST s), Ix i) => a i e -> (i,i)
ghci|     bounds arr = runST (getBounds arr)
ghci| 
<interactive>:8:25:
    Could not deduce (MArray a e (ST s1))
      arising from a use of `getBounds'
    from the context (MArray a e (ST s), Ix i)
      bound by the type signature for
                 bounds :: (MArray a e (ST s), Ix i) => a i e -> (i, i)
      at <interactive>:7:5-38
    ...
```

Wait a minute: `Could not deduce (MArray a e (ST s1))`?  Where'd that `s1` come from‽  We don't mention such a type variable anywhere!  The answer is that it's coming from the `runST` in the definition of `bounds`.  In general, `runST` has the type (renaming some type variables for convenience) `runST :: (forall σ. ST σ α) -> α`; when we use it here, we've constrained it to the type `(forall σ. ST σ (i,i)) -> (i,i)`.  What's happening here is that the `forall` is like a lambda (in fact, it *is* a lambda), binding `σ` locally inside the parentheses.  So when `getBounds arr` returns something of type `ST s (i,i)`, we can unify `α` with the `(i,i)`---but we *can't* unify the `σ` with the `s`, because the `σ` isn't in scope.  In GHC, the type variables for `runST` are `s` and `a`, not `σ` and `α`, so it renames `s` to `s1` to remove ambiguity, and it's *this* type variable that you're seeing.

So the error is fair: we've claimed that for some particular `s`, `MArray a e (ST s)` holds.  But `runST` needs that to be true for *every* `s`.  The error is, however, very unclear, since it introduces a new type variable which you can't actually refer to (so the "possible fix" is meaningless, although it's never helpful anyway).

Now, the obvious question is, "So can I write a correct type signature?"  The answer is "…sort of."  (But you probably don't want to.)  The desired type would be something like the following:

```
ghci> :set -XConstraintKinds -XRank2Types
ghci> let bounds :: (forall s. MArray a e (ST s), Ix i) => a i e -> (i,i)
ghci|     bounds arr = runST (getBounds arr)
ghci| 
<interactive>:170:25:
    Could not deduce (MArray a e (ST s))
      arising from a use of `getBounds'
    from the context (forall s. MArray a e (ST s), Ix i)
...
```

This constraint says that `MArray a e (ST s)` holds for *every* `s`, but we still get a type error.  It appears that ["GHC does not support polymorphic constraints to the left of an arrow"](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/7019#comment:3)—and in fact, while googling around trying to find that information, I found [an excellent blog post at "Main Is Usually A Function"](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2010/09/higher-rank-type-constraints.html), which runs into the same problem as you, explains the error, and provides the following workaround.  (They also get the superior error message "malformed class assertion," which makes clear that such a thing is impossible; this is probably due to differing GHC versions.)

The idea is, as is common when we want more out of type class constraints that we can get from GHC's built-in system, to provide explicit evidence for the existence of such a type class by (ab)using a GADT:

```
ghci> :set -XNoFlexibleContexts -XNoConstraintKinds
ghci> -- We still need -XRank2Types, though
ghci> :set -XGADTs
ghci> data MArrayE a e m where
ghci|   MArrayE :: MArray a e m => MArrayE a e m
ghci| 
ghci>
```

Now, whenever we have a value of type `MArrayE a e m`, we know that the value must have been constructed with the `MArrayE` constructor; this constructor can only be called when there's an `MArray a e m` constraint available, and so pattern-matching on `MArrayE` will make that constraint available again.  (The only other possibility is that your value of that type was undefined, which is why a pattern match is in fact necessary.)  Now, we can provide that as an explicit argument to the `bounds` function, so we'd call it as `bounds MArrayE arr`:

```
ghci> :set -XScopedTypeVariables 
ghci> let bounds :: forall a e i.
ghci|               Ix i => (forall s. MArrayE a e (ST s)) -> a i e -> (i,i)
ghci|     bounds evidence arr = runST (go evidence)
ghci|       where go :: MArrayE a e (ST s) -> ST s (i,i)
ghci|             go MArrayE = getBounds arr
ghci|   
ghci> -- Hooray!
```

Note the weirdness where we have to factor out the body into its own function and pattern-match there.  What's going on is that if you pattern-match in `bounds`'s argument list, the `s` from the `evidence` gets fixed to a particular value too early, and so we need to put this off; and (I think because inference with higher-rank types is hard) we also need to provide an explicit type for `go`, which necessitates scoped type variables.

And finally, returning to your original code:

```
ghci> let randShuffleST :: forall a e i g. Ix i => (forall s. MArrayE a e (ST s))
ghci|                                           -> a i e
ghci|                                           -> g
ghci|                                           -> (a i e, g)
ghci|     randShuffleST evidence arr gen = runST $ go evidence
ghci|       where go :: MArrayE a e (ST s) -> ST s (a i e,g)
ghci|             go MArrayE = do _ <- getBounds arr
ghci|                             return (arr, gen)
ghci| 
ghci> -- Hooray again!  But...
```

---

Now, as I said at the beginning, there's one problem left to address.  In the code above, there's never going to be a way to construct a value of type `forall s. MArrayE a e (ST s)`, because the contraint `forall s. MArray a e (ST s)` constraint is unsatisfiable.  For the same reason, in your original code, you couldn't write `randShuffleST` even without the type error you're getting, because you can't write a function which returns an `STArray` outside of `ST`.

The reason for both of these problems is the same: [an `STArray`'s first parameter is the state thread it lives on](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-ST.html#t:STArray).  The `MArray` instance for `STArray` is `instance MArray (STArray s) e (ST s)`, and so you'll always have types of the form `ST s (STArray s i e)`.  Since `runST :: (forall s. ST s a) -> a`, running `runST mySTArrayAction` would "leak" the `s` out in an illegal way.  Look into

[`runSTArray :: Ix i => (forall s. ST s (STArray s i e)) -> Array i e`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-ST.html#v:runSTArray)

and its unboxed friend

[`runSTUArray :: Ix i => (forall s. ST s (STUArray s i e)) -> UArray i e`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-ST.html#v:runSTUArray).

You can also use

[`unsafeFreeze :: (Ix i, MArray a e m, IArray b e) => a i e -> m (b i e)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:unsafeFreeze)

to do the same thing, as long as you promise that that's the last function you'll ever call on your mutable array; the [`freeze`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:freeze) function relaxes this restriction, but has to copy the array.  By the same token, if you want to pass an array, and not a list, into the pure version of your function, you'll probably also want

[`thaw :: (Ix i, IArray a e, MArray b e m) => a i e -> m (b i e)`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:thaw);

using [`unsafeThaw`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-MArray.html#v:unsafeThaw) would probably be disastrous here, since you're passing in an immutable array that you have no control over!  This would all combine to give us something like:

```
ghci> :set -XNoRank2Types -XNoGADTs
ghci> -- We still need -XScopedTypeVariables for our use of `thaw`
ghci> import Data.Array.IArray
ghci> let randShuffleST :: forall ia i e g. (Ix i, IArray ia e)
ghci|                   => ia i e
ghci|                   -> g
ghci|                   -> (Array i e, g)
ghci|     randShuffleST iarr gen = runST $ do
ghci|       marr  <- thaw iarr :: ST s (STArray s i e)
ghci|       _     <- getBounds marr
ghci|       iarr' <- unsafeFreeze marr
ghci|       return (iarr', gen)
ghci| 
ghci> randShuffleST (listArray (0,2) "abc" :: Array Int Char) "gen"
(array (0,2) [(0,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'c')],"gen")
```

This takes *O*(*n*) time to copy the input immutable array, but—with optimizations—takes *O*(1) time to freeze the mutable array for the output, since `STArray` and `Array` are the same under the hood.

Applying this to your problem in particular, we have the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
import System.Random
import Control.Monad
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad.ST
import Data.Array.ST
import Data.STRef
import Data.Array.IArray

updateSTRef :: STRef s a -> (a -> (b,a)) -> ST s b
updateSTRef r f = do
  (b,a) <- f <$> readSTRef r
  writeSTRef r a
  return b

swapArray :: (MArray a e m, Ix i) => a i e -> i -> i -> m ()
swapArray arr i j = do
  temp <- readArray arr i
  writeArray arr i =<< readArray arr j
  writeArray arr j temp

shuffle :: (MArray a e (ST s), Ix i, Random i, RandomGen g)
        => a i e -> g -> ST s g
shuffle arr gen = do
  rand           <- newSTRef gen
  bounds@(low,_) <- getBounds arr
  when (rangeSize bounds > 1) .
    forM_ (reverse . tail $ range bounds) $ \i ->
      swapArray arr i =<< updateSTRef rand (randomR (low,i))
  readSTRef rand

-- Two different pure wrappers

-- We need to specify a specific type, so that GHC knows *which* mutable array
-- to work with.  This replaces our use of ScopedTypeVariables.
thawToSTArray :: (Ix i, IArray a e) => a i e -> ST s (STArray s i e)
thawToSTArray = thaw

shufflePure :: (IArray a e, Ix i, Random i, RandomGen g)
            => a i e -> g -> (a i e, g)
shufflePure iarr g = runST $ do
  marr  <- thawToSTArray iarr
  g'    <- shuffle marr g
  iarr' <- freeze marr
  return (iarr',g')

shufflePure' :: (IArray a e, Ix i, Random i, RandomGen g)
             => a i e -> g -> (Array i e, g)
shufflePure' iarr g =
  let (g',g'') = split g
      iarr'    = runSTArray $ do
                   marr <- thaw iarr -- `runSTArray` fixes the type of `thaw`
                   void $ shuffle marr g'
                   return marr
  in (iarr',g'')
```

Again, you could replace freeze with `Data.Array.Unsafe.unsafeFreeze` in `shufflePure`; this would probably produce a speedup, since it wouldn't have to copy the array to return it if it was an `Array i e`.  The `runSTArray` function wraps `unsafeFreeze` safely, so that's not an issue in `shufflePure'`.  (The two are equivalent, modulo some details about splitting the PRNG.)

What do we see here?  Importantly, only the mutable code ever references the mutable arrays, and it stays mutable (*i.e.*, returns something inside `ST s`).  Since `shuffle` does an in-place shuffle, it doesn't need to return an array, just the PRNG.  To build a pure interface, we `thaw` an immutable array into a mutable array, shuffle *that* in-place, and then `freeze` the resulting array back into an immutable one.  This is important: it prevents us from leaking mutable data back into the pure world.  You can't directly mutably shuffle the passed-in array, because it's is immutable; contrariwise, you can't directly return the mutably shuffled array as an immutable array, because it's mutable, and what if someone could mutate it?

This doesn't run afoul of any of the errors we saw above, because all of those errors come from improper use of `runST`.  If we restrict our use of `runST`, only running it once we've assembled a pure result, all the inner state-threading can happen automatically.  Since `runST` is the only function with a rank-2 type, it's the only place where severe type-weirdness can be produced; everything else just requires your standard type-based reasoning, albeit perhaps with a little more thought to keep the `s` state-thread parameter consistent.

And lo and behold:

```
*Main> let arr10 = listArray (0,9) [0..9] :: Array Int Int
*Main> elems arr10
[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
*Main> elems . fst . shufflePure arr10 <$> newStdGen
[3,9,0,5,1,2,8,7,6,4]
*Main> elems . fst . shufflePure arr10 <$> newStdGen
[3,1,0,5,9,8,4,7,6,2]
*Main> elems . fst . shufflePure' arr10 <$> newStdGen
[3,9,2,6,8,4,5,0,7,1]
*Main> elems . fst . shufflePure' arr10 <$> newStdGen
[8,5,2,1,9,4,3,0,7,6]
```

Success, at long last!  (Way too long last, really.  Sorry about the length of this answer.)

Comment: I had no idea that my question would lead me down to such a deep rabbit hole... I'll need some time to fully understand your answer. But the fact that I have to use so many extensions and jump around so many hoops leads me to believe that shuffling an STArray in-place is practically impossible for most Haskellers. But, thank you very much for saying "mutable ST arrays can't meaningfully exist outside of the ST monad" --- this alone has has helped me a lot. +1 for breadth and depth of your explanation.

Comment: @opert: If I "[lead you] to believe that shuffling an STArray in-place is practically impossible for most Haskellers," then I gave you a bad answer! After all, look at [HaskellElephant's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12849728/237428)—you understood that, and it does exactly that! The goal of my answer was to guide you through *why* you get the error you do; the moral of the story (which I should be more explicit about) is that it's `runST`'s fault. If you follow the advice to keep `runST` on the outside, then your code will become quite simple. I'll edit my answer to include an example.